# Keep paragraphs together, in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm creating a bibliography, and have filling multiple pages, in paragraphs.

How can I stop word from splitting the paragraphs on the last lines of a page, and instead move the whole paragraph to the next page (so the reference isn't split across 2 pages, and there's maybe a small gap at the bottom of the prior page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Word 2010:

- Click on "Home" tab of the ribbon.
- At the very bottom of each section of the ribbon, there is a very wide, but quite low rectangle area containing a single word at the left side and a *very small and unremarkable* symbol at its right side.
- For me, those areas are labeled (from left to right): Clipboard - Font - Paragraph - [further items ...]. Click on the small symbol at the right side of "Paragraph".
- A dialog box titled "Paragraph" hopefully has opened. Click on the tab "Line and Page Breaks".
- Choose options as needed.

If you want existing paragraphs to be formatted according to those options, just select the respective paragraphs before performing the steps above. Otherwise, the new settings will be applied to the current paragraph only (i.e. that one where your cursor currently is) and eventually to new paragraphs.